# Push JS from npm module to browser in ApostropheCMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is it possible to push JS from an npm module to the browser in ApostropheCMS?

The file `lib/modules/my-module/public/js/custom.js` has been pushed to the browser with `pushAsset` successfully.

Three.js has been installed with `npm i three`.

Now `THREE` needs to get to the browser somehow for import, as described [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules).

I need to do this browserside:

```
var THREE = require('three');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require is a feature that comes with build tools like webpack or browserify. Those tools are not standard parts of apostrophe, nor are they built into browsers. You need to use a tool like webpack to compile code that contains require statements. So what you do instead is push the output files of your webpack pipeline as assets in apostrophe.

Comment: Ok, so there is no direct way of using JS from an npm module in the browser in apostrophe. This would be a great feature, but probably not the most requested one. Instead I placed the JS files in `puclic/js` and used `pushAsset` to forward them to the browser, this works, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it looks like version 3.x will have a webpack build you can opt into, although we strongly suspect people will just use the latest cool thing instead and push the output product to apostrophe, just like they do now. (: